# Is Apple developer team Id compulsory for Facebook instant game review process?

Tags: facebook-instant-games

Is Apple developer team id a must for Facebook instant game review process?
Is there a way to submit the Facebook instant game for review process without providing Apple developer team id if I don't want users using Apple devices to play the instant game?

Answer (score 1):

It is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/faq/#faq_2080054045606593):

> During submission for instant game app review, you must provide an
>   Apple Developer team ID in accordance with [Apple's App Store Review
>   Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). This enables distribution of your game on iOS. Using an
>   invalid or expired Developer team ID may lead to your game being
>   removed.